# need working example for WSO2 ESB

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

need working example for below link or similar

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/service-orchestration-with-wso2-esb/

from the above link i can able to 
1.create and deployed services in WSO2 ESB server .

but couldn't able to do from ESB configuration !!

i tried to downloaded and installed below two things but failed to do so ..

ESBArtifacts.zip
LicenseServiceProxyWSDL.xml

can some one help me with the step by step procedure to implementation in eclipse developer studio .

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/06/develop-and-deploy-esb-artifacts-using-wso2-developer-studio/) gives you step by step guide to use WSO2 Developer Studio to develop WSO2 ESB artifacts. After getting a basic understanding from the article, use WSO2 Developer Studio [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/WSO2+Developer+Studio+Documentation) for more details.